# Pagination not working on archive.php

Tags: pagination

I am using the WP Job Manager plugin and was able to point where the markup of **http://www.mywebsite.com/job-listings/** is used. It's set on a file called archive.php of my main theme.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-lg-<?php echo intval ( $colid ); ?> col-md-<?php echo intval ( $colid ); ?> col-sm-12 <?php echo esc_attr( $layout  ); ?>" data-layout="<?php echo esc_attr( $layout  ); ?>">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">
        <div class="articlesListing blog-grid"> 
            <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    if( !empty( $layout ) && $layout == 'masonry2-rsidebar'){
                        echo '<div class="construction-masonry">';
                    }
                        /* Start the Loop */
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            /* Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                             */

                            // Post Display Layout
                            if( !empty( $layout ) && $layout == 'masonry2-rsidebar' ) {
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'masonry' );
                            } else {
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                            }

                        endwhile;

                    if ( !empty( $layout ) && $layout == 'masonry2-rsidebar') {
                        echo '</div>';
                    }

                    the_posts_pagination( 
                        array(
                            'prev_text' => esc_html__( 'Prev', 'construction-light' ),
                            'next_text' => esc_html__( 'Next', 'construction-light' ),
                        )
                    );

                else :
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
                endif;
            ?>
        </div><!-- Articles Listings -->
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

However, when I go to the next page, eg. **http://www.mywebsite.com/job-listings/page/2**, it's displaying my 404 page. My search.php, however, works fine as it displays **http://www.mywebsite.com/page/2/?s=a** but I could not say the same for my Archives page. Is there something wrong on my pagination? Using Construction Light (main theme), Agency Bell (child theme).

Comment: is there a `query_posts` call somewhere before the code you shared? You should contact the job manager plugin and your themes support routes, 3rd party plugin/theme support is off topic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: Support for the plugin is quite unhelpful, which is why I resorted here for help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this after digging up some support posts on their support forum.

Add this under your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_job_listing', function( $array ) {
    $array['rewrite']['pages'] = true;
    return $array;
} );
```

REFERENCE: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-not-working-in-job-listing-archive/